# How extract the specific word from a file that has some characters present in it?

Tags: python, regex, search, extract

I have a file `log.txt` that contains:

```
Router:94.126.126.109
Name:nl-rtm02a-ra2
show running-config interface^M
^MWed Jul 11 12:42:03.409 CET^M
! ****  Configuration start **** RING  rt72-central  RA2 ****^M
! # RING INTERFACE CONFIGURATION^M

 service-policy output NA4-PM-FRFB+COS^M
 ipv4 address 84.116.244.181 255.255.255.252^M
 bundle minimum-active links 1^M
 load-interval 30^M
 flow ipv4 monitor NA4-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
 flow ipv6 monitor NA4-IPV6-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
!^M
interface Bundle-Ether1001^M
 description ** ICL to RA2-SAT1 **^M
 vrf NV_Mgmt^M
 ipv4 point-to-point^M
 ipv4 unnumbered Loopback1000^M
 load-interval 30^M
 flow ipv4 monitor NA4-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
 flow ipv6 monitor NA4-IPV6-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
 nv^M
  satellite-fabric-link satellite 1001^M
   remote-ports GigabitEthernet 0/0/0-43^M
  !^M
 !^M
!^M
interface Bundle-Ether2000^M
 description ** LACP Uplink to rt53cbr68 **^M
 mtu 9192^M
 bundle minimum-active links 1^M
 load-interval 30^M
!^M
interface Bundle-Ether2000.251^M
 description ** rt53abr68 IPv4 B-Side **^M
 vrf 03109128:NL_CMTS_ACCESS^M
 ipv4 mtu 1500^M
 ipv4 address 212.142.4.45 255.255.255.252^M
 flow ipv4 monitor NA4-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
 flow ipv6 monitor NA4-IPV6-MONITOR-MAP sampler NA4-SAMPLER-MAP ingress^M
 encapsulation dot1q 251^M
!^M
interface Bundle-Ether2000.651^M
 description ** rt53dbr68 IPv6 B-Side **^M
 ipv6 nd prefix default no-autoconfig^M
 ipv6 address 2a02:a200:40:56::1/64^M
 encapsulation dot1q 651^M
!^M
interface Bundle-Ether2000.701 l2transport^M
 description ** BSOD SDN-NFV Traffic rt53cbr68 **^M
 encapsulation dot1q 2501-2699^M
```

In this file I need to extract the words that contain `"cbr"`, `"abr"`, `"dbr"` and store it in a CSV file.

For example, in the above content, I want to extract:

```
1.rt53cbr68 
2.rt53abr68 
3.rt53dbr68
```

I tried the below code:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
searchlines = f.readlines()


for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "cbr" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]:
           print l
```

And one more thing I wanted to get the router value from file content and store it in a variable..

Comment: So what's the *problem* with the code you've posted? You're currently only checking for one of the three things, so maybe look at `or`.

Comment: `fabric` also contains `abr`.  Do you wish to match words where `crb`,`abr` and `dbr`are preceded and followed by numbers?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I want to extract that specific word not entire string..

Comment: So look into `str.split` or `re`. Give a [mcve] that actually illustrates the specific question.

Comment: @pkpkpk - Ohh sorry I haven't noticed that.. I just want that word which is present in description line.

Comment: @pkpkpk - It can be many..Later i will filter only the unique one.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the line doesn't really matter, this is why I would suggest using read() instead of readlines(), and use split() to return a list of each word (using split() would split your text separated by " " and "\n").

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    words = f.read().split()
    routerNames = []
    z = 1
    for wrd in words:
        if ("cbr" in wrd) or ("abr" in wrd) or ("dbr" in wrd):
            routerNames.append(str(z)+ ". " + wrd)
            z+=1

    with open("file2.txt","w") as g:
        g.write("\n".join(routerNames))
```

Note : This code would get all words containing these characters, even the ones you don't want. I would suggest adding another condition to minimize the errors.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    words = f.read().split()


    for wrd in words:
        if (("cbr" in wrd) or ("abr" in wrd) or ("dbr" in wrd)) and ("rt" in wrd):
            ...
```

Comment: And one more thing I wanted to get the router value from file content and store it in a variable.How do i do that..?

Answer (score 0):

This would match any description line containing `abr` or `cbr` or `dbr`

```
>>> import re
>>> list(enumerate(re.findall(r'description.*\s(.*?[cad]br.*?)\s', data)))
[(0, 'rt53cbr68'), (1, 'rt53abr68'), (2, 'rt53dbr68'), (3, 'rt53cbr68')]
>>>
```

Comment: -And one more thing I wanted to get the router value from file content and store it in a variable.How do i do that..?

Comment: Use `re.search`. Something like `rtr = re.search(r'Router:\s*(.*?)\s', data).group(1)`

Answer (score 0):

To match your values you might use a regex with [finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer).

You could match one or more word characters `\w+` and one or more digits `\d+`, then use a character class `[cad]` which would match any of those characters followed by `br` and one or more digits.

For the router value you might use a named group `(?P<router>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)` and positive lookbehind `(?<=` to assert what is on the left side is `Router` preceded by a word boundary `\b`.

To match either of them  and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|`

[`(?<=\bRouter:)(?P<router>\d+(?:\.\d+)+)|\w+\d+[cad]br\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vKvYB8/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/DWUY43034)